# Where i can find Mapbox tiles gallery

Tags: openstreetmap, tiles, mapbox

I have discovered that cloudmade tiles service has been discontinued, so to switch to mapbox tiles, i imagine that i can find a gallery (like in cloudmade ) where i can choose the tiles style convenient. i searched a lot, i've just found a [demo made by a techslides](http://techslides.com/demos/mapbox/mapbox-styles.html).

where i could find a place where users shares thier style or any gallery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mapbox provides a gallery of their own stuff using [tilestream](https://github.com/mapbox/tilestream):

http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox/maps.html

I would also be interested to know if there are any sites for collections of third party basemaps.